# Symfony 1.4 backend get the filtered query

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to export the list, that previously filtered in the backend filters. How can I get the filtered list in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres `buildQuery()` method:

```
$q = $this->buildQuery();
/* @var $q Doctrine_Query */
$objects = $q->execute();
```